# Button in asp.net is not doing any function when i press the submit button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When i Press the Submit button after filling the form the form is refresh but data is not submitted in the Database and i am trying to store data using the stored procedure.
Thanks

[Button Code]

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
     <asp:Button ID="Submit_Button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" runat="server" onClickButton="Submit_Form_Click" Text="Submit" />
 </div>
```

[ASP.NET Code Behind]

```
 protected void Submit_Form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string Sponsirship_TypeValue = Sponsirship_Type.SelectedValue;
      string Select_Gender = Gender.SelectedValue;
      string Marital_Status = MaritalStatus.SelectedValue;
      string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Student_Registration", con);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      SqlParameter paramReg_Num = new SqlParameter("@PHD_Registration_Number", Session["LoginUserName"]);
      SqlParameter paramSponsirship_Type = new SqlParameter("@SponsershipType", Sponsirship_TypeValue);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      Response.Write("Number of Changes" + result);
 }
```

Comment: if you set a breakpoint and run it it should be easier :) do you get an error?

Comment: Let me check it sir

Comment: Sir i used Breakpoint my Code for button is not executing so there is no error please help me.

Comment: Did you set that breakpoint within "Submit_Form_Click"? it should trigger if you use it

Comment: Yes i set it at the starting of submit_form_click but it didn't trigger

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with your page button

Answer (score 1):

Replace *onClickButton* with [OnClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.8):

Example:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
           Text="Submit"
           OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Thanks bro its working bur there is an error i need to resolve it now thanks